# how to access static method in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

**Controller Name :** Rforce_TaskUtils_CLS

My controller has a method as

```
public static void onAfterInsert(list <Task> listtask, boolean isInsert, Map <Id, Task> oldMap )
```

In my test clas, I have tried to access the above method as

```
Rforce_TaskUtils_CLS.onAfterInsert(List <Task> listtask, boolean isInsert, Map <Id, Task> oldMap);
```

It shows error like :

> unexpected token: 'List' at line 13 column 38

How to resolve this?

Complete test class code is :

```
 @isTest
 public class TaskTriggerHandlerforRforce_Test { 

   public static testMethod void aftIns()
   {
      Rforce_TaskUtils_CLS.onAfterInsert(List <Task> listtask, boolean isInsert, Map <Id, Task> oldMap);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are You Defining objects again whhile calling the class.

Try putting objects in the parameter while calling.

`public static List listtask ; 
 public static boolean firstRun ; 
 public static Map oldMap ;
 Rforce_TaskUtils_CLS.onAfterInsert(listtask,isInsert,oldMap);`

Comment: i tried wat u said. but it shows error like : Variable does not exist: listtask at line 13 column 39

Comment: @ram451 in order variable to be use in static method,should it be static variable also?

Comment: Define the Variable First then call the Method. and ofcourse Varible should be static.

Comment: cant get you.. can u pls provide the syntax ?

Comment: Both of the answers above show what to write.  Rajeev has comments where you should put values.  I don' t know if you have a testFactory created, but you could use one to create that mock list and the map.  For now I'd just make them equal to a query of whatever you're trying to put in the collections.  isInsert is just true or false.

Answer (score 1):

```
List <Task> listtask = //Some list;
boolean isInsert = //true or false;
Map <Id, Task> oldMap = //some map;
Rforce_TaskUtils_CLS.onAfterInsert(listtask,isInsert,oldMap);
```

Please try like this.